# box2D (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, box2d

I am just getting started with box2d. I am able to create some objects and create a world in which to use those objects. For example, to create a box (taken from: http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html) I can do so like this:

```
    elements = getElementsByClass("box2d");
      for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++ ) {
        properties[i] = getElementProperties( elements[i] );
        bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
        var data = { element: elements[i]};
        bodyDef.userData = data;
        fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
        fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(2 //half width ,  2);
        bodyDef.position.x = Math.random() * 10;
        bodyDef.position.y = Math.random() * 10;
        world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
      }
```

What I would like to do is take divs with text and turn those divs with text into shapes and use them in box2D. I really don't know where to start with this. I am using the userData property now thinking that this is at least a start.

I found a great example of this in action here: http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google_gravity/

getElementProperties and getElementsByClass are defined. I was thinking about using getElementProperties to set the shape dimensions.

Comment: Reading through the code on that example it seems like you can just rip that code, however I don't see an open source license so legally you can't. If you could just set all of the elements in the HTML that you want to be box2d elements with that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar with iOS, but a good way to approach it is to make images out of the information held in the div. Then you can make a sprite out of that image and add it as the userData for your box2d body. When you update (tick: method in iOS, I am not sure for javascript) then you iterate over all the bodies and adjust the sprite location. The box2d world should do everything else for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference this samples..

http://jsbin.com/efequk/5

http://www.jeremyhubble.com/box2d.html

Comment: I like the examples but do you have something simpler. Possibly something that just displays a circle or some simple object on the screen.